# joining arrays with concat and using a loop

Tags: javascript

I run into the following problem, the following array: `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]` I must go through it and get the following result `[1, 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`. Currently I get the same result. Here my code:

```js
 let main= [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

 let result= [].concat(
   main.map((e)=>{
     return e
   })
 )

 console.log(result)
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat

Comment: `map(e => e)` (equivalent to your code) basically just produces a copy of the original array. You want `reduce`, or better yet, `flat`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey if `concat` is to be used, then `[].concat(...main)` can also work.